Derivative of inner product of matrices $A$ and $B$ is just $B.$ i.e. $ d_A \langle A | B \rangle = B$
Let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d} .$
How to show that the derivative of $f(A) = \langle A | B \rangle  $ with respect to A is B where  $\langle A | B \rangle$ is defined as the inner product of matrices i.e. $$  \langle A | B \rangle = \sum_{i,j} A_{ij} B_{ij}$$
It comes from a proof that shows that the MLE of covariance of a multivariate Gaussian is the empirical variance, i.e.
$$ \hat \Sigma _{MLE} = \frac 1 n \sum_1^N (x_i-\hat\mu_{MLE})(x_i-\hat\mu_{MLE})^T$$
See page 4 of the class notes.

The derivative is the best linear approximation. Your map is already linear.

What have you tried?

Note that $F(A)-F(B)-F(A-B) = 0$, from this you can see that $f$ is its own derivative.

I guess what I am confused about is the definition of matrix-valued function. Is this definition correct:
$f$ is differentiable at $A$ if and only if there exists some linear operator $d_{f_A}$ such that for any small $\delta$ $f(A+\delta) - f(A) = \langle d_{f_A} , \delta \rangle + \text{o} (||\delta||)$.

@Fiori_Modena Yes, see my previous comment, clearly $0 $ is $o( | \delta |)$.

For $A,B \in R^{d\times d} $ and $f(A)=\langle A | B \rangle = \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}B_{ij},$ $f$ is differentiable at $A$ if and only if there exists some linear operator $d_{f_A}$ such that for any small $δ \in R^{d\times d}$ we have that $f(A+δ)−f(A)=⟨d_{f_A},δ⟩+\text{o}(||δ||).$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
f(A+δ)−f(A) 
&= \langle A | B + \delta \rangle - \langle A | B \rangle \\
&= \sum_{i,j} (A_{ij}+\delta)B_{ij} - \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}B_{ij} \\
&=  \sum_{i,j} (A_{ij}+\delta)B_{ij} - A_{ij}B_{ij}  \\
&=  \sum_{i,j} B_{ij}[(A_{ij}+\delta) - A_{ij}]  \\
&=  \sum_{i,j} B_{ij} \delta   \\
&=   \langle B | \delta \rangle + 0.
\end{align*}
From the above equation, we can see that $d_{f_A} = B $ satisfies the definition of differentiability, as required to show.
